# Как сохранить pdf файл из iframe на сервере?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax, asp.net

Веб-приложение ASP.NET Core MVC + c#

В представлении есть вот такой код:

```
<form asp-action="AnketSave" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h2>Анкета</h2>
                <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" />
                <iframe src="~/Ankets/Anketa.pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 800px;"></iframe>
</form>
```

В pdf файле есть checkbox'ы, которые может установить пользователь.
Мне нужно через POST сохранить изменённый файл в папку wwwroot/UserAnket.
Не могу понять как его выдернуть из iframe

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пользователь не может изменить файл в iframe. При загрузке страницы он получает свою **копию** этого PDF-файла. Все изменения с этим остаются на его локальном компьютере.

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже понял!